# Ceiling fan light fixture blew

Tags: lighting, switch, ceiling-fan

I mistakenly put in a dimmer light bulb and, when I pulled the string to turn on the lights, it blew the light fixture of my ceiling fan.  I've tried changing the bulbs, but the fixture isn't working at all.

Comment: Welcome.What's your question? What does "blew the fixture" mean? Is there visible damage? What sort of fixture is it? Please [revise your question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/175714/edit) to be more clear so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a lower wattage bulb this would not cause any problems, the fixture wiring may have shorted out tripping the breaker, or causing a wiring failure at a backstab splice. More information is needed to try and help. But a dimmer bulb would not be the cause unless the bulb itself had an internal short causing the breaker to trip or a wiring failure.